# error connection.play is not a function in discordjs v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i was trying to create a bot and I was trying to do from a youtube tutorial and I think its because I'm using discord.js v13 so if anyone can tell me how to downgrade to a lower discord.js version that could also be a solution but if someone knows how to solve this problem then please review my code and help me. the versions of the dependencies I'm using are-

```
"@discordjs/opus": "^0.6.0",
"@discordjs/voice": "^0.6.0",
"@types/ws": "^7.4.7",
"discord-api-types": "^0.22.0",
"discord.js": "^13.1.0",
"ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
"ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.0",
"tiny-typed-emitter": "^2.1.0",
"yt-search": "^2.10.1",
"ytdl-core": "^4.9.1"
```

keep getting this message -

the code in index.js=

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
   const fs = require("fs");
   const config = require("./config.json");

const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });

const prefix = "-";

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("client is ready");
});
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
// const commandFiles = fs
//   .readdirSync("./commands/")
//   .filter((file) => file.endsWith(`.js`));
// for (const file of commandFiles) {
//   const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
//   client.commands.set(command.name, command);
// }
// client.commands.get(command).execute(client, message, args, command, Discord);

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  console.log(file);
  console.log(command);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "hello") {
    message.channel.send("hey there chutiyon");
  } else if (command === "ping") {
    client.commands.get("ping").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "play") {
    console.log(client.commands);
    client.commands.get("play").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "leave") {
    client.commands.get("leave").execute(message, args);
  }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

the code in play.js=

```
const ytSearch = require("yt-search");
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require("@discordjs/voice");
module.exports = {
  name: "play",
  description: "this is play command",
  async execute(message, args) {
    // const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    console.log(message);
    console.log(args);
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
      guildId: message.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });
    // await voiceChannel.join();
    const VideoFinder = async (query) => {
      const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
      return videoResult.videos.length > 1 ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
    };
    console.log(VideoFinder);
    const video = await VideoFinder(args.join(""));
    console.log(video);
    if (video) {
      const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: "audioonly" });
      console.log("---------------------------------------");
      console.log(stream);
      console.log(typeof connection.play);
      await connection
        .play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1, type: "opus" })
        .on(finish, () => {
          voiceChannel.leave();
        });
      await message.reply(`:thumbsup: nowplaying ----${video.title}---`);
    } else {
      message.channel.send("video not found");
    }
  },
};
```

```
.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1, type: "opus" })
         ^

TypeError: connection.play is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\pc\WE_SOO_NOOBLA_BOT\commands\play.js:30:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to call `.play()` on the voice channel? As opposed to the video itself or the stream?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `joinVoiceChannel` function?

Comment: It's best you stay on v13 and update the changes required

Answer (score 3):

You can not call `.play()` on a **[`voiceConnection`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/voiceconnection.html)**, one has to create an **[`AudioPlayer`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioplayer.html)** instance and further **[`subscribe`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/playersubscription.html)** to this player, you would have to do some base additions for the same which are exhibited below:

```js
const {
    joinVoiceChannel,
    createAudioPlayer,
    createAudioResource
} = require('@discordjs/voice');

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: message.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});

const stream = ytdl(video.url, {
    filter: "audioonly"
});

const player = createAudioPlayer();
const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

async function play() {
    await player.play(resource);
    connection.subscribe(player);
}
```

They just made it overly complicated for no good reason, anyways if you ever feel like downgrading you may create a file called `main.sh` with the contents in the following code block or just commands in the code block given below

```sh
npm uninstall discord.js
npm install discord.js@12.5.3
```

Comment: kinda sus how youtubers are making tutorials with wrong codes 

Comment: I was just about to answer this; nice answer. Some relevant documentation: [`VoiceConnection`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/voiceconnection.html), [`PlayerSubscription`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/playersubscription.html), [`AudioPlayer`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioplayer.html).

Comment: Thankyou @Cannicide let me propose an edit with the documentation